# 3D surface plot in julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I would like to know how may I plot the data from following code as `3D-surface`?

```
using Plots
function f(x)
    x1=x[1]
    x2=x[2]
    sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2])
end
#Sampling
function sam()
    x = range(0, 10.0, length = 9) |> collect
    y = range(0, 10.0, length = 9) |> collect
    tuple = zip(x,y) |> collect
    return tuple
end
xy = sam()
z = f.(xy)
plot(getindex.(xy,1),getindex.(xy,2),z)
```

I have tried using `st=:surface` in the `plots()` function with both `gr()` and `pyplot()` as backend but it doesn't work.
May I know how can i plot this as surface within `x,y,z` limits?

Comment: for your ranges and function, the syntax is simply: `surface(x, y, f)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want to do

```
julia> using Plots

julia> f(x, y) = sin(x) + cos(y)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> surface(0:0.1:10, 0:0.1:10, f)
```

which gives

[image]

If you want to explicitly build the grid, you could do

```
julia> x = y = 0:0.1:10
0.0:0.1:10.0

julia> z = f.(x', y) ; # note the ' which permutes the dims of x

julia> surface(x, y, z)
```

Comment: handy solution, but I just wanted to point out the hilariously unfortunate concatenation of 10 on the x-axis with 0 on the y-axis to produce something that very much looks like 100 lol